# Woocommerce Variation dropdown <select><options> doesnt allow arrow key navigation

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, select, woocommerce

On all my woocommerce websites. Product variation dropdowns do not allow arrow keys to navigate once selected.

For example if you select an option from the dropdown. It "unselects" itself.

If you wana navigate to the next one down with your arrow key you have to "re-select" the option you just selected and than press the arrow key at which point it goes to the next one down and unselects itself again.

I noticed this is on all my woocommerce sites regardless of theme but you can replicate the issue here: http://demo.polr.me/6

Does anyone know what is breaking the ability to use keyboard arrows to navigate options in a select field? Is there some jquery i can add to force it to remain selected?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for keyboard change value and change style as per your requirement

```js
    jQuery('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">+</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">-</div></div>').insertAfter('.quantity input');
    jQuery('.quantity').each(function() {
      var spinner = jQuery(this),
        input = spinner.find('input[type="number"]'),
        btnUp = spinner.find('.quantity-up'),
        btnDown = spinner.find('.quantity-down'),
        min = input.attr('min'),
        max = input.attr('max');

      btnUp.click(function() {
        var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
        if (oldValue >= max) {
          var newVal = oldValue;
        } else {
          var newVal = oldValue + 1;
        }
        spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
        spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
      });

      btnDown.click(function() {
        var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
        if (oldValue <= min) {
          var newVal = oldValue;
        } else {
          var newVal = oldValue - 1;
        }
        spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
        spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
      });

    });
```

```css
.quantity {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number]
{
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.quantity input {
  width: 45px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.quantity input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.quantity-nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
}

.quantity-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  line-height: 1.7;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-up {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="9" step="1" value="1">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but how does this apply to woocommerce select fields not staying selected?